# How to make a servlet interact with the API of a website and also store the XML response?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String text = "some text";

    response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
    response.getWriter().write(text);       // Write response body.
}
```

If I use this servlet , where request variable will have the url of the API of the website . Then how do I capture the response ? I would want to know what is the code to do that , and is this the right way to go about it when trying to build a JSP page that deals with interacting with an API of a website and showing data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing things. The `HttpServletRequest` is the HTTP request which the client (the webbrowser) has made to reach the servlet. The `HttpServletResponse` is the response which you should use to send back the result to the client (the webbrowser).

If you want to fire a HTTP request programmatically, you should use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://example.com").openConnection();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream(); // This contains the response. You need to convert this to String or some bean and then display in JSP.
```

#### See also:

- [How to use `java.net.URLConnection` to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)